# Error message when trying to Publish Node.js Express to Azure (setup_web.cmd missing)

Tags: azure, express, visual-studio-2017, publish, file-not-found

In Visual Studio 2017, I create a new Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 App. On the *Project* tab, I click Convert to *Microsoft Azure Cloud Service project...*. I do not do any further coding.

Next, in the Solution Explorer, I right-click on the thus created .Azure project and click on *Publish...*.

After filling in my credentials for my MS account, I follow all the steps in the Microsoft Azure Publish dialog. Somewhere it says *Creating New Application Insight resource*, then in the status bar it say *Publish started...*

Then, after a short while, I get the following message:

*CloudServices64: Cannot find file named 'approot\bin\setup_web.cmd' for startup task setup_web.cmd > log.txt  of role ExpressApp10*

Can anyone please tell me what this means and what I can do about it?

Kind regards,

John Pool

Comment: is the copy to output property of the file is copyalways?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the' file?

Comment: the cmd  file that was not found as per the error you had posted.

Comment: At the risk of me being considered stupid: I do not see that file (setup_web.cmd) anywhere, let alone that I can see or change one of its properties.